# Android market "Whats new in version xyz" - information

Tags: android, google-play

While browsing through various apps in the market, I noticed that there's a "New in version xyz: ... " text, just above the number of downloads and comments. Did I miss something, or is there a dedicated field to provide this kind of information while uploading a new version of your app in the market instead of just changing your application description?

Thanks

Edit: Here a picture to clarify what I'm talking about:

[image: what's new dialog]

Comment: AFAIK, that's just a convention for the description field.

Answer (score 2):

That's the developer overstuffing the `versionName` name field in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.foomatic"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.02 Fixed inaccurate frobnostication"
>
...etc...
```

Not great practice, but it doesn't chew up any of the limited number of characters available in the description.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks for that...in that case that's not very practicable -.-

Answer (score 0):

Market implementation has been changed and now there is a field for "what's new" so this practice of "stuffing the version" isn't required any more.